# resize image to the height of a frame

Tags: html

I'm creating a web site that have a frame on the bottom to let's say 10% of screen.
I would like to put a logo on the left of that frame, all nice until now, but.

I hope you remember that frame is a percent of all screen, then I would like to resize logo image to fit the height of the frame no matter how big or small the screen is (and the frame is).

I just spent 4 hours searching and testing, without success :(

It is that possible ? How ?

Answer (score 0):

Add these styles.

```
   #yourframe{width:10%; height:20%;}//Your frame
   #yourimage{width:100%; height:100%;}//Your Image
```

Comment: thanks for your interest, i did tried something that ... not working :(, image is at full size outside visible area, i can scroll down in frame to see it in full, but still at full size even if i disable scroll bars ... can you post an explicit piece of code that is working ? ... please